# Video View in List view

Tags: android, listview, video, video-player

I am working on a chat app and now I want to play video and audio files in my `ListView`. I am able to play these in activity but not in adapter class. Below is my complete code. And know even I am not able to hide play button and start progress bar. Thanks in advance.

This is the XML file.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:emojicon="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"


android:gravity="right"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:paddingTop="5dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblMsgFrom"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/lblFromName"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:textStyle="italic" />


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cardviewchat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    card_view:contentPadding="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/file_icon"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fileextention"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:text="taste.txt"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtMsg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_msg_you"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="16dp" />


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/imgmsg"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    />


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/video_frame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="480px"
    android:background="#000"
    android:visibility="gone"
    >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/VideoView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        />



    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/play_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone" />


</FrameLayout>
```

And this is my Adapter class

```
public class MessagesListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private List<MessageV> messagesItems;
private VideoView videoview;
private ImageButton Playbutton;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
String VideoURL = "";

public MessagesListAdapter(Context context, List<MessageV> navDrawerItems) {
    this.context = context;
    this.messagesItems = navDrawerItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return messagesItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return messagesItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    /**
     * The following list not implemented reusable list items as list items
     * are showing incorrect data Add the solution if you have one
     * */

    MessageV m = messagesItems.get(position);

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    // Identifying the message owner
    if (messagesItems.get(position).isSelf()) {
        // message belongs to you, so load the right aligned layout
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_message_right,
                null);
    } else {
        // message belongs to other person, load the left aligned layout
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_message_left,
                null);
    }

    TextView lblFrom = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblMsgFrom);
    TextView txtMsg = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtMsg);
    ImageView imagemsg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgmsg);
    CardView cartdv = (CardView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cardviewchat);
    TextView msgtext = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fileextention);
    FrameLayout videoviewframe =(FrameLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.video_frame);
    videoview = (VideoView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
    Playbutton = (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.play_button);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
    Playbutton.setTag(position);
    lblFrom.setText(m.getFromName());




  if(!m.getFile().equalsIgnoreCase("")){

      String string = m.getFile();
      String[] parts = string.split("files\\/");
      String part1 = parts[0]; // 004
      String part2 = parts[1];
      Log.d("part1",part1);
      Log.d("part2",part2);
      String[] exten = part2.split(Pattern.quote("."));
     String part3 = exten[1];

      if(part3.equalsIgnoreCase("png")||part3.equalsIgnoreCase("jpg")||part3.equalsIgnoreCase("jpeg")){
          imagemsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          txtMsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          Picasso.with(context).load(m.getFile()).into(imagemsg);
      }else if(part3.equalsIgnoreCase("mpeg")) {
          txtMsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          videoviewframe.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }else{
          txtMsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          cartdv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          msgtext.setText(part2);
      }


  }else{
     txtMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     imagemsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     txtMsg.setText(m.getMessage());
 }

   // imagemsg.setImageBitmap(m.getFile());


    Playbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int pos = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(v.getTag()));
            Playbutton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //pDialog.show();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            VideoURL=messagesItems.get(pos).getFile();
           // VideoPlay();

            try {

                MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(
                        context);
                mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
                // Get the URL from String VideoURL
                Uri video = Uri.parse(VideoURL);
                videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
                videoview.setVideoURI(video);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            videoview.requestFocus();

            videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                // Close the progress bar and play the video
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    //pDialog.dismiss();

                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                    ((Activity)context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
                    int h = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
                    int w = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
                    // Start the MediaController
                    videoview.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(w, h));

                    videoview.start();
                }
            });
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Videoview does not work well with scrolling views like listview and recyclerview. Check this link on how its can be implemented

https://medium.com/@v.danylo/implementing-video-playback-in-a-scrolled-list-listview-recyclerview-d04bc2148429

Hopefully you find it useful